# MVC3 Session Start event fires twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I thought the session_start event in the global.asax should only fire the first time I access a page on the web site.  But I noticed for in asp.net mvc3 when I go to different paths it runs every time.

Ex.

```
http://webserver/home/index - runs once here (link 1) 
http://webserver/contact/index - runs once here (link 2)
```

Do I need to configure something so session_start only runs once? I tested this by setting a session variable to current date time and displayed the session variable on the layout page.  When I click on linked 1 from above it displayed a time and when I clicked on link 2 from above it displayed a time.  Both times were different.   Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Check out this post it will answer your question


[Session Start fires multiple times][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097758/session-start-firing-multiple-times-on-default-asp-net-mvc3-project

Comment: Thanks Pratik. That was the answer. Can you post your response below then I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Actually its still occurring for me.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If `Session_Start` or `Session_End` handlers are not defined in the `Global.asax`, a new Session ID is generated for every request, when there is nothing stored in the Session bag.This is what happening in your case

similar, [ASP.Net Session_Start always firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885276/asp-net-session-start-always-firing)

Comment: never knew that. never had a global.asax either. but kool to know.

Comment: I have the event defined in the global.asax.